# What is the intended use of the 400 Hz-rated power supply on osciloscopes?

Tags: power-supply, oscilloscope, mains, industrial

The power supply of many oscilloscopes and other test equipment from different manufactures are commonly rated for 400 Hz operation. For example, Tektronics MDO3000 is rated to work at 400 Hz at 115 VAC. Rigol MSO7000 is rated at 100-240 VAC, 45 Hz-440 Hz.

I'm aware that 400 Hz power supply is widely-used in aerospace, and I heard some military and industrial installations also use 400 Hz, mainly to reduce the weight of the transformer. But I didn't find any specific case online.

What are some specific scenarios when users are expected to connect the oscilloscope to a 400 Hz power supply? Using an oscilloscope on a flying aircraft sounds unplausible. Most laboratories, industrial or otherwise are likely supplied with 50/60 Hz AC to power all equipment. The only possibly I can think of is field-engineers doing tech support. But even then, I believe it's more common to use a portable, battery-powered oscilloscope.

Does anyone who has an industrial background can explain: Is that really difficult or inconvenient to find a standard mains-frequency power in some factories to make it justified for most oscilloscope manufacturers to rate their scope for 400 Hz operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that’s what it means. Planes often use 400 Hz generators and the plane’s frame becomes “Earth ground”.

As always, Gnd just means 0V anywhere in the universe and Earth bonded implies 0V to earth ground with some impedance <100 Ohms each to another grid location with an earth ground, unless in dry remote areas with poor earth bonding.

Earth is used  by all 3 pin instruments to bypass EMI line filter leakage currents only and provide a good low impedance reference for scope probe ground leads.Sometimes DSO’s will put a plastic cap or an inductor between 0Vdc and Earth gnd pin for various reasons to isolate earth ground common mode RF  noise (L), or block AC current but bypass RF to a relatively low impedance AC gnd using a cap only.

Engineers do use DSO’s on planes for R&D work.

Comment: *"Engineers do use DSO’s on planes for R&D work"* Wow, how common is it? Do they use it for maintenance? Developing a device related to aircraft? Or is it that sometimes the schedule is so tight that you need to do R&D on planes during your business trip?

Comment: Aircraft testing is done in the flying thing. Same as train and car testing. It's done in the running thing.

Comment: dont' forget ships... ships do run on 400Hz as well because most of the time they use a jet engine for propulsion

Comment: When I applied for a job at DLR, one of the first things they asked if I would board an untested helicopter … trick question!

Comment: @Janka haha , sure with landing gear firmly attached to  gnd.  The beauty is, experienced pilots can land with a dead engine but not a dead rotor or dead electrical

Comment: @Janka fascinating. Did you work on “Smartfish”? Or just apply for a job?

Comment: Nah, they were interested but I started my own business instead.

Comment: The military in general uses 400 Hz 3-phase where possible just to get the extra efficiency from downstream ferrite-core transformers.

Comment: @Sparky256 I thought the primary reason was diesel 2000 RPM and 24 poles per Rev to reduce weight of all magnetics in the system for transport costs for the same efficiency and reduce C sizes for supplies that rectify line voltage.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 It was about efficient power distribution as well.